# MS Access Error 434 stops creating xlBarStacked in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, charts, vba, ms-access-2016

Since the last couple of weeks, I have been dealing with exporting a query and create a chart.
I have to change the chart design to xlBarStacked. Thas my problem

The below piece code is working well:

```
Sub exportqrycreatechart()
Dim xl, wb, ws, ch, mychart, chart, qry_01 As Object
Dim sExcelWB As String

   Set xl = CreateObject("excel.application")
   On Error Resume Next

   Err.Clear
   On Error GoTo 0
   sExcelWB = CurrentProject.Path & "qry_01"
   DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "qry_01", sExcelWB, True

   Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(sExcelWB)
   Set ws = wb.Sheets("qry_01")
   Set ch = ws.Shapes.AddChart

   Set mychart = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
   ws.Columns.AutoFit
   ws.Columns("B:C").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
   ws.Columns(3).TextToColumns , , , , -1, 0, 0, 0
   ws.Columns(4).TextToColumns , , , , -1, 0, 0, 0

  wb.Save
  xl.Visible = True
  xl.UserControl = True
  Set ws = Nothing
  Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

However, when I try to change the chart to xlBarStacked, an 'error 434 object does not support this property or method' occurred.

```
With ch
    .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 59
    .ChartArea.Height = 400
    .ChartArea.Width = 700
    .ChartArea.Top = 1
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete '

    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))

    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown))
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))
    .Axes(xlCategory).ReversePlotOrder = True
End with
```

Error 434 occurs in:

```
.ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 59
```

and all lines down

Here is all code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub exportqrycreatechart()
    Dim xl, wb, ws, ch, mychart, chart, qry_01 As Object
    Dim sExcelWB As String

       Set xl = CreateObject("excel.application")
       On Error Resume Next

       Err.Clear
       On Error GoTo 0
       sExcelWB = CurrentProject.Path & "qry_01"
       DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "qry_01", sExcelWB, True

       Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(sExcelWB)
       Set ws = wb.Sheets("qry_01")
       Set ch = ws.Shapes.AddChart

       Set mychart = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
       ws.Columns.AutoFit
       ws.Columns("B:C").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
       ws.Columns(3).TextToColumns , , , , -1, 0, 0, 0
       ws.Columns(4).TextToColumns , , , , -1, 0, 0, 0

         With ch
            .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 59
            .ChartArea.Height = 400
            .ChartArea.Width = 700
            .ChartArea.Top = 1
            .FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete '

            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))

            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown))
            .FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))
            .Axes(xlCategory).ReversePlotOrder = True
         End with

      wb.Save
      xl.Visible = True
      xl.UserControl = True
      Set ws = Nothing
      Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me how I can solve this? I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

You've got about 3 problems there that I can see. First, `Shapes.Addchart` returns a `Shape`, not a `Chart`, which is why you're getting the 438 error. Second, you have a couple of unqualifed excel object references, which will cause you to have orphaned Excel processes. Third, you appear to be late binding but you are trying to use constants from the Excel library, which will have no value in your code.

Try this instead:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub exportqrycreatechart()
    Dim xl, wb, ws, ch, mychart, chart, qry_01 As Object
    Dim sExcelWB As String
    Const xlCenter As Long = -4108
    Const xlCategory As Long = 1
    Const xlDown As Long = -4121

       Set xl = CreateObject("excel.application")
       On Error Resume Next

       Err.Clear
       On Error GoTo 0
       sExcelWB = CurrentProject.Path & "\qry_01.xlsx"
       DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "qry_01", sExcelWB, True

       Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(sExcelWB)
       Set ws = wb.Sheets("qry_01")
       Set ch = ws.Shapes.AddChart.chart

       Set mychart = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
       ws.Columns.AutoFit
       ws.Columns("B:C").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
       ws.Columns(3).TextToColumns , , , , -1, 0, 0, 0
       ws.Columns(4).TextToColumns , , , , -1, 0, 0, 0

         With ch
            .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 59
            .ChartArea.Height = 400
            .ChartArea.Width = 700
            .ChartArea.Top = 1
            .SeriesCollection(1).Delete '

            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown))

            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(2).Values = ws.Range("D2", ws.Range("D2").End(xlDown))
            .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = ws.Range("C2", ws.Range("C2").End(xlDown))
            .Axes(xlCategory).ReversePlotOrder = True
         End With

      wb.Save
      xl.Visible = True
      xl.UserControl = True
      Set ws = Nothing
      Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Again Error 438 occurred here: "With ch .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 59". This line down is where the error occurs. I am still confused. If I omit this line, the error occurs in the line down and so on.

Comment: @SebastianSalazar Did you *replace* your code with mine, or try and add the changed lines in?

Comment: I've just amended the code further as there was an error in the path and workbook name too (so I'm suprised you got as far as you did!) and ran it in 2010 without issue, after changing `FullSeriescollection` to `Seriescollection` since that was added after 2010. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using MS Office 2016
In Excel, I copied the code with macro recorded `on.´
There, I saw `.fullSeriesCollection´

I move `seriescollection´ code and "Set axis min-max values code block" to within `With ch - End´ With

But, when executing the code, after ending Excel in Task  Adm..'Error 462 the remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable', ocurred in this line
`.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = ws.Range("C2", ws.Range("C2").End(xlDown))´

Now, will VBA show in the Chart the CurrentRegion Range at a time with my `seriescollection´ data Range of my Code?

Comment: Make sure you have terminated all Excel processes before running the code, since your code would have left some running.